# My session contains map. How to access that map in javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp, session, dictionary

How can I access my session attribute having map in javascript and assign the value of map in jsp scriplet?

Comment: convert your map into json

Comment: COuld you please elaborate more?

Comment: first you should share some code that you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this? ?
    ${map[key]}